# In excel with a Pivot table, don't show rows with no data

Tags: excel, pivot-table, mdx

I've got a pivot table of employees and the hours and number of shifts they worked in a month.  I made a calculated measure that shows Yes if the total hours is above 160, no if it's below 160, and blank if it's below 1.

The measure looks like this: IIF([Measures].[Hours]<1,"",IIF([Measures].[Hours]>=160,"Yes","No"))

I have it filtered to only show the month of August, and it only shows employees who worked in August.

Once I add the calculated measure to the table, it shows all employees that every worked in any month, with blank values for the number of hours.

How do I get it to only show employees who worked at least one hour?  There's no filter available above the hours column, and when I try to drag it to the filter box it says, "The field you are moving cannot be moved to that area of the report".

Answer (score 0):

Empty string ("") is not the same as NULL.

Return NULL for your first `IIF` `true` condition and see whether it gives you the desired output

```
IIF
(
  [Measures].[Hours] < 1
 ,NULL
 ,IIF
  (
    [Measures].[Hours] >= 160
   ,"Yes"
   ,"No"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I'm familiar with null in the context of sql, I just didn't know excel used null in the same way.  I'll give that a try.